# AppleScript Numbers Retreiving Cell Value

Tags: applescript, numbers

I have a script which loads a Numbers document in order to retrieve a specific cell value to use in creating a reminder.

My code is below. I believe I'm using correct syntax to load the value into a variable, but I'm just getting a `0` in the reminder and the dialog doesn't show.

```
set transferValue to 0

tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    try
        open filePath
        tell sheet "Monthy Expected"
            tell table "Account Budget Share"
                set transferValue to value of cell "B4"
                display dialog value of cell "B4"
                display dialog transferValue
            end tell
        end tell
    on error

    end try
end tell
```

Is there something wrong with what I have done? The correct file is opened when I run the script, but none of the subsequent commands seem to execute. It just opens the document and then continues on to the reminders.

Comment: what is 'open filepath'? I don't think that line works and because it is in a 'try', the whole thing fails without getting a chance to display the dialog but also without comment. If I remove the 'try/error' lines, I get a 'variable filePath is not defined' error. Also, I don't think you have the syntax correct for the document/sheet/table. Try including the document among your 'tells'.

Comment: In the code you've shown `filePath` is not defined, however, assuming it is and the document is actually opened then here are some issues: 1. There is nothing on in the `on error` _handler_ to let you know what the _error_ is. 2. Your are missing `tell document 1` before `tell sheet ...`. 3. `display dialog value of cell "B4"` needs to be: `display dialog (get value of cell "B4")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified example, showing minimal *code*, to replicate what's shown in your OP, and as you can see in the **Replies** *pane* of **Script Editor** in the image further below there are no errors and both `display dialog` *commands* returned the expected *value*.

**Numbers Document**

[image]

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set transferValue to 0

tell application "Numbers" to ¬
    tell table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1
        set transferValue to value of cell "B4"
        display dialog (get value of cell "B4")
        display dialog transferValue
    end tell
```

**Script Editor** showing the results of running the *code*:

[image]